# How to assign data from an asynchronous function in nextjs 14

Tags: javascript, next.js13

I have a problem in nextjs 14, I have a js file with an asynchronous function that I show below:

```
import { getTranslations } from 'next-intl/server';

export const getDescripcion = async (tema) => {
  const t = await getTranslations(tema);
  const arrayDescripcion = [];

  ['1', '2'].map((contenido) => {
    arrayDescripcion.push(t(`secciones.conflictos.descripcion.${contenido}`));
  });

  return arrayDescripcion;
};
```

I am trying to use what this function returns in a nextjs page, my doubt is can I assign that result of the asynchronous function to a variable to pass it as prop to the Section component that I create.

```
import { Hero, Section } from '@/components';
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl';
import { getTranslations } from 'next-intl/server';

import { getDescripcion } from '@/hooks/getData';

export async function generateMetadata({ params: { locale } }) {
  const t = await getTranslations({ locale, namespace: 'Gestion' });

  return {
    title: t('titulo_metadata'),
    description: t('descripcion_metadata'),
  };
}

const Gestion = () => {
  

  return (
    <>
      <Hero
        title={t('titulo')}
        description={t('descripcion')}
        color='0, 0, 0'
        img='https://res.cloudinary.com/eparionad/image/upload/v1707358241/arcoIris-beta/portada_GS_300x_11zon_nuukz7.webp'
        position='right 65% bottom 45%'
      />
      <Section
        title={t1('titulo')}
        description={arrayConflicto}
        carousel={salidas}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Gestion;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this async function for the value which can be passed further down. However, you would need to add `await` keyword in front of the function. Like below -

```
const description = await getDescripcion(); // correct the typo in your code
```

Comment: But if I do that outside of the Management function, I get the following error:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/140Bez9mssBkSV6izsNjuLMvUidfCi5eI/view?usp=sharing, But if I do that outside of the Management function, I get the following error:
But if I place it inside the Gestion function, I have to put async in Gestion and I get the following error:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19UppWXkA0o8RNd-5r2GsFD1cmlVTW9R9/view?usp=sharing,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19z9wM_IiEv_K8Ey4o_-hS_682M2AgYmU/view?usp=sharing.